# Filter out first 6 elements from DataSet

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two identical tables, both of which have the same java List as their datasource. This cannot be changed.

In the first table, I have to **list out the first 6 elements**:
I simply set the rightclick>properties>filter to

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() <= 6
```

But in the second table, I need **every list element other than the first 6**. If I simply try

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() > 6
```

It wont work, I guess because the REPORT_COUNT variable never gets incremented, because the first 6 rows doesnt get added into the Table.

Is there a way to do this, without changing the dataset itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in the Table component:
Right click>edit table datasource, here I specified that inside my bean, which list I want the table to use.

The solution was to simply use .sublist(6, mylist.size()) here.